# Selecting from a table that contains ALL of another table

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Let's say I have three tables:

```
Employees:
       PID NAME                       WAGE
---------- -------------------- ----------
     10234 Able                          8
     11567 Baker                         9
      3289 George                       10
     88331 Alice                        11

Employee_made:
       PID        SID   QUANTITY      HOURS
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
     10234         11         24          3
     10234         12          6          1
     10234         13         24          1
     10234         21          6          1
     10234         23          4          1
     10234         31         48          6
     11567         23          4          1
     11567         31          1          1
     88331         11          6          1

Sandwich:
       SID      PRICE NAME                         
---------- ---------- ------------------------------
        12          2 hamburger on wheat            
        13          2 cheese burger                 
        21       1.75 fish burger on rye            
        23       1.75 fish burger on wheat          
        31          3 veggie burger on wheat        
        11          2 hamburger on rye
```

I need to list all the employees who have made ALL the different sandwiches, and display their names and PID. What I've gotten so far is:

```
Select E.name, E.pid 
From employees E, employee_made EM, sandwich S
Where E.pid = EM.pid
```

Which tells me the matching PIDs from the employees and employee_made table. Where I'm not sure to go is how to display the employees who have made ALL the sandwiches, so matching not any SID to the employee_made table, but ALL of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, *never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

You can approach this by counting the number of sandwiches mades by employees and then comparing to the total count of sandwiches:

```
select em.pid
from employee_made em 
group by em.pid
having count(distinct em.sid) = (select count(*) from sandwich);
```

This gives the `pid` of the employee.  I'll let you figure out how to bring in the employee name (hint:  `in`, `exists`, and `join` could all be used).

Comment: Is this cheating? 'Select E.name, E.pid
From employees E
Where E.pid = (
  select em.pid
  from employee_made em 
  group by em.pid
  having count(distinct em.sid) = (select count(*) from sandwich)
);
'

Comment: @BryanE . . . It is not "cheating".  You will just get an error if you try it and the subquery returns more than one row.

Comment: Why would that throw an error if there was more than one row returned?